# Prevent eclipse from jumping over auto-added closing parentheses

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

If I type an opening parenthesis in Eclipse editor (Photon, 4.8.0), it automatically adds a closing parenthesis right next to it, with my cursor in between. This is fine.

What's not fine: Now as soon as I press Tab or Enter, instead of indenting or going to a new line, the cursor jumps to the right of the auto-generated closing parenthesis.

How can I keep the auto-added closing parenthesis but disable the cursor-moving behaviour?

I'm using Eclipse CDT, in case that matters.

Comment: I guess this behavior is hard-coded in the auto-close parentheses feature and you have to press Esc (or Shift+Tab) before Tab or Enter if you don't want to turn off the feature (_Window > Preferences: C/C++ > Editor > Typing_).

Comment: So then it would be another one of those intelligent features that actually cause additional key presses instead of saving them. Thanks for pointing out the page for disabling that. I wished the Eclipse developers (or UX people in general) would focus more on creating a Preferences page that's actually navigable instead of trying to outsmart the user.

Comment: I (as Java developer) like the current behavior (which is the same in the Java editor). If you want a different behavior, [report it to Eclipse CDT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-editor). If you have good examples of when the user is outsmarted here, I'm sure it will be implemented.

Comment: How often do you actually want a tab or a newline between parentheses?

Comment: Quite often, as each argument of a function declaration/definition gets a separate line. So do function calls with 3+ arguments due to the coding styleguide I am bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Eclipse CDT, in case that matters.

It does matter, as this functionality is implemented per-language.

I'm not familiar with other language implementations, but I can tell you about CDT: the only configuration option that's currently implemented is whether to auto-add the closing parenthesis or not. If the option is enabled (which is the default), you get the behaviour you described when pressing Tab or Enter with it.

That said, it should be fairly straightforward to add another option to control this behaviour. You're welcome to [file a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT), and [contribute a patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development) if you'd like; I'm happy to provide guidance for writing a patch and review it.